# TBMP not getting game updates unless it is player's turn

Tags: android, google-play-games, multiplayer

I am trying to include TBMP into my Mahjong game and this issue has been stuck with me for a few months now, and I am no closer to resolving it.

I have four players in a game and the game progressing counterclockwise.  So imagine you have four players at a table:

```
                        Player 3
           ---------------------------
Player 4 |                                |    Player 2
           ---------------------------
                       Player 1
```

Now Player 1 takes a turn, the data is pushed via JSON into the game data, and Player 2 gets notified that it is his turn.  Player 3 and 4 also get a notification that a match update has occurred, but when they query the game data, it returns the stale game information, unless it becomes their turn, then they get the accurate and current game data.

I would like all players to be updated after every turn, rather than getting all the updates in one go when it becomes their turn.

I register an update listener as follows:

mTurnBasedMultiplayerClient.registerTurnBasedMatchUpdateCallback(mMatchUpdateCallback);

I have a function that processes the update as follows:

```
private TurnBasedMatchUpdateCallback mMatchUpdateCallback = new TurnBasedMatchUpdateCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onTurnBasedMatchReceived(@NonNull TurnBasedMatch turnBasedMatch) {

     int turnStatus = turnBasedMatch.getTurnStatus();

     // OK, it's active. Check on turn status.
     switch (turnStatus) {
        case TurnBasedMatch.MATCH_TURN_STATUS_MY_TURN:

           MainActivity.mTurnData = 
             MahjongTurn.unpersist(turnBasedMatch.getData());
           setLocalGameValues();
           state = GameState.Playing;
           return;

        case TurnBasedMatch.MATCH_TURN_STATUS_THEIR_TURN:

           MainActivity.mTurnData = 
             MahjongTurn.unpersist(turnBasedMatch.getData());
           setLocalGameValues();
           state = GameState.MultiWait;
           return;
     }


  }

  @Override
  public void onTurnBasedMatchRemoved(@NonNull String matchId) {
     game.showToast("A match was removed.");
     state = GameState.MultiWait;
     return;
  }
```

};

Anyway, the listener is registered correctly and I can see that my listener gets called, but the call to turnBasedMatch.getData() only returns the correct game data when it is also the player's turn.

So Player 4 gets the updates from Player 1, Player 2 and Player 3 only when it becomes his turn.  He gets notified that there is an update to the match, but has no way of knowing what the current game data looks like.

Is this the way it is meant to work?  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you check the turn-taking guide in [turn taking GPGS](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/turnbasedMultiplayer#turn-taking) There's also [github repo](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples) for code reference.

Comment: Yes I have checked the flow and the examples.  Examples work perfectly, but they are a very simple case.  My game is much more complex.  In the example they only create a Toast when the listener is called for a game update.  I am actually trying to update the game data and display the updated game based upon the update, however, the game data does not change to reflect the update (in my case).

Comment: When you debug, does the code ever enter the THEIR_TURN switch?  Also, you've repeated code in both switch states.  All of the code in each state is literally identical except for one line (the state variable).  I'd move all of that code to before the switch takes place, and leave the state as the only line in each switch case.

Comment: Thanks Timothy.  Yeah I know the code is sloppy, but it is like that because I am experimenting with commenting parts out, until it works correctly.

In terms of the question, yes, I can verify that it does actually get the callback for both THEIR_TURN and MY_TURN, but the game data is stale, until it is MY_TURN.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround for this is to store all the turns inside the message data.  This way, I can treat the game data like a Message Queue and replay everything up to the current turn.  This is not ideal, but it works.